# Why does Apache get a 404 when trying to include SSI from another server?

Tags: apache, ssi

I have two web sites that produce data that I would like to combine into one web page. *Site one* (the "main" site) produces most of the web page, and *site two* contains additional data that I want to include on that page.
I figure the best way would be to use SSI to include data from *site two* into the web page produced by *site one*.  Apache on *site one* seems to contact *site two* properly, but *site two* returns a 404.  If I contact *site two* directly with a browser, using the exact same URL that *site one* is using, I get proper data. Why wouldn't Apache on *site one* get the same data?

I've tried two ways to include the data from *site two*, one directly and one using a reverse proxy, but neither works. Other (local) SSIs and reverse-proxies work fine on this page.  These are the two include lines:

```
<!--#include virtual="/servertwodata" -->
<!--#include virtual="http://www.servertwo.com/execs/somescript.sh?task=overview" -->
```

The error that I get in the Apache error log is:

```
unable to include "http://www.servertwo.com/execs/somescript.sh?task=overview" in parsed file /var/www/html/index.html, subrequest returned 404, referer: http://www.serverone.com/index.html
```

Does anyone have a clue why Apache on *site one* would get a 404 from *site two*, but the exact same URL in a generic browser would get the data fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that reverse proxy does discards any query string that is included as part of the proxypass configuration parameter.  I removed the query string from the proxypass parameter and moved it to the SSI ***include virtual*** tag, and it no longer gets the 404 from *site two*.
The response that is put on the web page is scrambled hieroglyphics, but what's causing that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#includevirtual):

> The value is a (%-encoded) URL-path. The URL **cannot contain a scheme or hostname**, only a path and an optional query string. If it does not begin with a slash (/) then it is taken to be relative to the current document.

In short: It doesn't support external URLs.

Comment: I guess that explains why the "direct" attempt doesn't work, which was kind of a shot in the dark anyway because I couldn't get the reverse-proxy thing to work.  Any idea why the reverse-proxy doesn't work?  I'm using reverse-proxy in other places on the same page, to other external servers (although not with SSI), and it works ok.  Are reverse-proxy and SSI not compatible with one another?